# Why W3C ask to drop empty arcs?

Tags: svg

We can read in the [Appendif F : Implementation Requirements > F.6 Elliptical arc implementation notes](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/implnote.html#ArcOutOfRangeParameters) the following :

> If the endpoints (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) are identical, then this is equivalent to omitting the elliptical arc segment entirely.

This looks to me very strange for the following reasons :

- If an empty A segment is between a C and S, when we drop this segment the interpretation of S changes.
- This rule is inconsistent with other rules : why not omit empty lines or empty curves, but omit empty arcs ?
- The browsers (Chrome, Firefox) don't follow this rule. For example if we drop the empty arc from `M 0 0 C 0 10 10 10 10 0 A 10 10 0 0 0 10 0 S 20 -10 20 0` we obtain a non equivalent path `M 0 0 C 0 10 10 10 10 0 S 20 -10 20 0`.

[image]

**So my question is: do we have to respect this rule if we write an SVG library?**

Answer (score 2):

The browsers are following the rule just fine.  "Omitting" doesn't necessarily mean completely ignoring its existence.  They can omit rendering it, but they should not ignore its coordinate values when interpreting S and T path commands.

Comment: "omitting the elliptical arc segment entirely" is very precise and is not "omit rendering". And we can apply the rule "omit rendering" to any other 0 length segment like  `l 0 0` for example. But why this specific rule only for arcs ?

Comment: Check [this rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/implnote.html#PathElementImplementationNotes) for zero-length paths. They are not "omitted"

Comment: The rules you link to are talking about rendering the end caps of a zero-length line. I am referring to not rendering the degenerate (zero-length) path segment itself.

Comment: If the rule is what you say, why this rule is only for arc segments ? why not the same rule for line segments ?

Comment: While I find browsers' implementation is the obvious one (e.g if an arc comes to this position during a SMIL animation and the pathSeg is indeed removed, the whole animation would break), I also do find that the Appendix is a bit unclear here. IMO, it could be rewritten to *"If the endpoints (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) are identical, then go to the next command directly"*.